# Can I assign the TAB key to Zen coding's Expend Abbreviation command in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, emmet

I installed Zen Coding for the Microsoft Virtual Studio 2010.

```
Zen Coding v0.7 by Sergey Chikuyonok
Visual Studio Plugin v0.7 by Danny Su
```

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/924090a6-1177-4e81-96a3-e929d7193130

I would like to be able to use the TAB key in order to use Zen Coding's Expend Abbreviation command (instead of ALT-Z) when editing HTML documents like in Sublime Text 2.

I go to Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard and choose ZenCoding.ExpandAbbreviation but when I type the TAB key in the box to Assign the key it doesn't work.

Any idea? Is it possible?

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible sadly. I tried following this guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228753.aspx , to set the hotkey via my own add-in. I was able to set the hotkey to Tab and when I opened to Zen Coding toolbar next to Expand Abbreviation is says Tab, but when I hit tab nothing happens. If you are lucky enough to upgrade to VS2013 I think emmet is now bundles with Web Essentials plugin. If you get this working on VS2010 please post as I would love to get this working too.